# How to find response type inajaxError handler?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to find the response type in `ajaxError` callback. I tried with `jqxhr.contentType` but it was undefined.

May I know how can I find the response type in `ajaxError` handler? google doesn't much help me. Appreciate if I get a reference link.

Comment: Where is you actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ajaxError` callback returns [four objects](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/) as parameters. You can use the third object to get `contentType`.

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event,jqXHR,settings,thrownError){
    alert(settings.contentType);
});
```

edit: This will give you the request's content Type. For getting the response's content type, Use the following code.

```
var ct = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
```